# Is it possible to save multiple users using omniauth-facebook rails gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth

I have the following code in user.rb using the Facebook-omniauth gem that logs in a single user:

```
 def self.from_omniauth(auth)
where(auth.slice(:provider, :fb_id)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
  user.provider          = auth.provider
  user.fb_id             = auth.uid
  user.name              = auth.info.name
  user.first_name        = auth["info"]["first_name"] unless auth["info"].blank?
  user.last_name         = auth["info"]["last_name"] unless auth["info"].blank?
  user.picture_url       = auth.info.image
  user.email             = auth.info.email
  user.oauth_token       = auth.credentials.token unless auth["info"].blank?
  user.location          = auth.info.location unless auth["info"].blank?
  user.save!
end
```

I want to build user accounts for multiple facebook users. When I log its fine but when another person signs in, the app replaces my user instance. Is there a way to keep building user accounts from this gem?

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm - I'm a little confused by the question. Can you give an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Do I need a user management gem like Devise to have more than one user with Facebook Omniauth? It appears that there's always only 1 user, who ever logged in last.

Comment: What I want to do is when another user logs in, they are saved in the User database, not overriding the first user. Is that clear enough @wyclin?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was in the second line at: `where(auth.slice(:provider, :fb_id))`

I changed it from :uid to :fb_id to match the facebook id of everything else in all my other tables but after inspecting the `auth` hash I realized that :fb_id was not found at all and thus wasn't producing any new Users.

I renamed my User `fb_id` column back to `uid` and it now collects new users properly:

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
      user.provider          = auth.provider
      user.uid               = auth.uid
      user.name              = auth.info.name
      user.first_name        = auth["info"]["first_name"] unless auth["info"].blank?
      user.last_name         = auth["info"]["last_name"] unless auth["info"].blank?
      user.picture_url       = auth.info.image.sub("square", "large")
      user.email             = auth.info.email
      user.oauth_token       = auth.credentials.token unless auth["info"].blank?
      user.location          = auth.info.location unless auth["info"].blank?
      user.save!
    end
  end
```